# give css to checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am new to CSS.

I want to give CSS to checkbox just shown in the image.

[image: here is the image]

i have tried but checkbox is appearing on the screen and when I select one of the category then it background would be yellow.

Thank You.

```css
.radio_toggle {
  float:left;
}

.radio_toggle label {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  overflow:auto;

}

.radio_toggle label span {
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding:5px 0px;
  display:block;

}

.radio_toggle label input {
  position:absolute;
}

.radio_toggle .venue {
  background-color:#edf1f2;
  color: #58666e;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  border: thin #ced9db solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;

}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
 <div class="radio_toggle">
    <label class="venue" style="">
      <input type="checkbox" name="toggle">
         <span>Category</span>
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="categories">
  <div class="radio_toggle">
    <label class="venue" style="">
       <input type="checkbox" name="toggle">
           <span>Category</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="categories">
  <div class="radio_toggle">
       <label class="venue" style="">
           <input type="checkbox" name="toggle">
               <span>Category</span>
       </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you like to change the color If it's selected.

Comment: yes.. like in the back there should be a checkbox and on upper side it look like a box or button. when selected then color should get changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the `input`, give it `display: none;`, updated CSS rule

```
.radio_toggle label input {
  display: none;
}
```

To give the *button* a color use the `:checked` selector, added CSS rule

```
.radio_toggle label input:checked + span {
  color: white;
  background: gold;
}
```

Sample

```css
.radio_toggle {
  float:left;
}

.radio_toggle label {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  overflow:auto;

}

.radio_toggle label span {
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding:5px 0px;
  display:block;

}

.radio_toggle .venue {
  background-color:#edf1f2;
  color: #58666e;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  border: thin #ced9db solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;

}

.radio_toggle label input {
  display: none;
}

.radio_toggle label input:checked + span {
  color: white;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
 <div class="radio_toggle">
    <label class="venue" style="">
      <input type="checkbox" name="toggle">
         <span>Category</span>
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="categories">
  <div class="radio_toggle">
    <label class="venue" style="">
       <input type="checkbox" name="toggle">
           <span>Category</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="categories">
  <div class="radio_toggle">
       <label class="venue" style="">
           <input type="checkbox" name="toggle">
               <span>Category</span>
       </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @UnknownDeveloper, you have to use javascript for that.
Make a new class `.venue_selected` and give your desired colors. Then use click event for all elements to add class to label and check respective checkbox.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .radio_toggle {
      float:left;
    }

    .radio_toggle label {
      float:left;
      width:100px;
      overflow:auto;

    }

    .radio_toggle label span {
      text-align:center;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding:5px 0px;
      display:block;

    }

    .radio_toggle label input {
      position:absolute;
    }

    .radio_toggle .venue {
      background-color:#edf1f2;
      color: #58666e;
      /*min-height: 100% !important;*/
      border: thin #ced9db solid;
      border-top-left-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .radio_toggle .venue_selected{
        background: #f9d342  !important;
        color: #ffffff !important;
    }

    .categories input[type="checkbox"] {
      display: none;
    }
</style>

<div class="categories">
    <div class="radio_toggle">
        <label class="venue" style=""><input type="checkbox" name="toggle"><span>Category</span></label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="categories">
    <div class="radio_toggle">
        <label class="venue" style=""><input type="checkbox" name="toggle"><span>Category</span></label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="categories">
    <div class="radio_toggle">
        <label class="venue" style=""><input type="checkbox" name="toggle"><span>Category</span></label>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var elms = document.querySelectorAll("label.venue");
    elms.forEach(function(el,i) {
        el.onclick = function() {
            console.log(el);
            el.classList.toggle("venue_selected");
            el.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']").click();     
        }       
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you. i have done it without JS. thank you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using 2 methods.

Either using JavaScript or CSS.

For CSS it's very simple. You have to use the `:checked` attribute.

```
.radio_toggle[type=checkbox] + label {
  // Code on how to look before checked
} 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  // Code on how to look after checked
}
```

For JS you first have to get the `radio_toggle` element using and then listen for if it's checked which for your case will look something like this

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("radio_toggle").checked = true;
function check(element) {
    element.checked = true;
    element.style.color = "Color you desire"

}
```

Comment: thank you. i have done it without JS. thank you.. :)